# Make image appear in separate section when thumbnail clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking to have an image appear in a separate section after a thumbnail of the image is clicked in an above section.

index code:

```
        <section id="select-image">
        <h2>Step 1. Select an image</h2>
        <p>Select your prefered image</p>
        <div id="ug-images"><img src="/images/ugimage1.jpg"></div>
    </section>
    <section id="add-text">
        <h2>Step 2. Add Text</h2>
        <input id="text" type="text" value="Customise me!">
    </section>
    <section id="style-image">
        <h2>Step 3. Style it!</h2>
        <div id="workspace">
```

javascript code:

```
    $(document).on('click', '#ug-images', function() {
  var url = $(this).data('url');
  $("#workspace img").remove();
  var img = $("<img>").attr('src', url);
  $("#workspace").append(img);
});
```

To be clear. I want the thumbnail selected in id=Select-image to appear in id=workspace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply create a copy of the image and append it to workspace

```
var $workspace = $('#workspace'), //simply caching the selector
    $img = $();

$('#ug-images').on('click', 'img', function () {
    $img.remove();
    $img = $(this).clone().appendTo($workspace);
});
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FpsLJ/

Comment: This one is perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/fSyPp/

```
$(document).on('click', '#ug-images', function () {
    var url = $(this).attr('src');
    $("#workspace img").remove();
    var img = $("img").attr('src', url);
    $("#workspace").append(img);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to deal with the URL attribute. You can clone the clicked image and append it to the "#workspace"

```
$(document).on('click', '#ug-images', function () {
  var $newImg = $(this).clone();
  $('#workspace').append($newImg);
});
```

Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/7jSkx/

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#ug-images").click(function(){
        $("#workspace img").remove();
        var url = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
        alert(url);
        $('#workspace').html('<img  src="'+url+'" />')
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

If you want to show the selected image only

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wY79Z/)

```
 $(document).on('click', '#ug-images', function() {
 var img = $(this).find('img').clone();
 $("#workspace").html(img);
});
```

or
If you want to append the each image you clicked

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wY79Z/1/)

```
$(document).on('click', '#ug-images', function() {
 var img = $(this).find('img').clone();
 $("#workspace").append(img);
});
```